# Separate FastApi documentation into sections

Tags: python, openapi, fastapi

Currently the OpenAPI documentation looks like this: [image: documentation aspect]
Is it possible to separate it into multiple sections?

For example, 2 sections, one being the "books" section that contains the methods from "/api/bookcollection/books/" endpoints and the other containing the endpoints with "/api/bookcollection/authors/".

I have consulted the FastApi [documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/extending-openapi/), but I do not find anything close to the operation I want to do.

Comment: the question has been marked as solved, and also, your reference is more recent than this question.

Comment: also, it seems to be the same solution as the selected answer, therefore, there is no point in analyzing the other solution.

Comment: My apologies. I will leave the related answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72915808/how-to-create-a-custom-sort-order-for-the-api-methods-in-fastapi-swagger-autodoc/73210294#73210294

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `OpenAPI` [allows](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/grouping-operations-with-tags/) the use of *tags* to group endpoints. `FastAPI` also supports this feature. The documentation section can be found [here](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/metadata/#metadata-for-tags).

Example:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI

tags_metadata = [
    {
        "name": "users",
        "description": "Operations with users. The **login** logic is also here.",
    },
    {
        "name": "items",
        "description": "Manage items. So _fancy_ they have their own docs.",
        "externalDocs": {
            "description": "Items external docs",
            "url": "https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/",
        },
    },
]

app = FastAPI(openapi_tags=tags_metadata)


@app.get("/users/", tags=["users"])
async def get_users():
    return [{"name": "Harry"}, {"name": "Ron"}]


@app.get("/items/", tags=["items"])
async def get_items():
    return [{"name": "wand"}, {"name": "flying broom"}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another solution for this would be just to create different routers for every resource that you want to have in different documentation sections.

[source](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/bigger-applications/)