# How to create a custom sort order for the API methods in FastAPI Swagger autodocs?

Tags: python, swagger, swagger-ui, fastapi, openapi

How can I set a **custom** sort order for the API methods in [FastAPI Swagger autodocs](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/features/#automatic-docs)?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24951268/sort-api-methods-in-swagger-ui) shows how to do it in Java. My [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72904923/how-to-sort-methods-in-fastapi-swagger-api/72905007?noredirect=1#comment128786562_72905007) asked how to sort by "Method", which is a supported sorting method. I would really like to take this a step further, so that I can determine which **order** the methods appear. Right now `DELETE` appears at the top, but I want API methods to be in the order: `GET`, `POST`, `PUT`, `DELETE`.

I know it is possible to implement a [custom sort in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24951268/sort-api-methods-in-swagger-ui) and give that function to [`operationsSorter`](https://swagger.io/docs/open-source-tools/swagger-ui/usage/configuration/), but you can't include it from the [`swagger_ui_parameters`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/extending-openapi/#change-default-swagger-ui-parameters) property that is available in the Python bindings. Is there some way to accomplish this in Python?

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI(swagger_ui_parameters={"operationsSorter": "method"})

@app.get("/")
def list_all_components():
    pass

@app.get("/{component_id}")
def get_component(component_id: int):
    pass

@app.post("/")
def create_component():
    pass

@app.put("/{component_id}")
def update_component(component_id: int):
    pass

@app.delete("/{component_id}")
def delete_component(component_id: int):
    pass
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`tags`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/path-operation-configuration/#tags) to group your endpoints. To do that, pass the parameter `tags` with  a `list` of `str` (commonly just one `str`) to your endpoints. Use the same tag `name` for endpoints that use the same `HTTP` method, so that you can group your endpoints that way. For example, use `Get` as the tag name for `GET` operations (**Note**: `Get` is only an example here, you can use any tag `name` you wish).

Doing just the above would most likely define the endpoints in the order you wish (i.e., `GET`, `POST`, `PUT`, `DELETE`). However, to ensure this—or, even in case you would like to define a different order for your methods/tags—you could [add metadata for the different tags used to group your endpoints](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/metadata/#metadata-for-tags). You could do that using the parameter `openapi_tags`, which takes a `list` containing one `dictionary` for each tag. Each dictionary should at least contain the `name`, which should be the same tag `name` used in the `tags` parameter. [**The order of each tag metadata dictionary also defines the order shown in the docs UI**.](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/metadata/#order-of-tags)

### Working Example

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI

tags_metadata = [
    {"name": "Get"},
    {"name": "Post"},
    {"name": "Put"},
    {"name": "Delete"}
]

app = FastAPI(openapi_tags=tags_metadata)

@app.get("/", tags=["Get"])
def list_all_components():
    pass

@app.get("/{component_id}", tags=["Get"])
def get_component(component_id: int):
    pass

@app.post("/", tags=["Post"])
def create_component():
    pass

@app.put("/{component_id}", tags=["Put"])
def update_component(component_id: int):
    pass

@app.delete("/{component_id}", tags=["Delete"])
def delete_component(component_id: int):
    pass
```