# How should I organize my path operations in FastAPI?

Tags: python, crud, fastapi, endpoint

I am creating an application with FastAPI and so far it goes like this:

[image]

But I'm having a problem with the endpoints. The /api/items/filter route has two query parameters: name and category.
However, it gives me the impression that it is being taken as if it were api/items/{user_id}/filter, since when I do the validation in the documentation it throws me an error saying that I have not passed a value for user_id. (Also, previously it asked me to be authenticated (the only route that needed authentication was api/items/{user_id}.
The problems are fixed when I define this endpoint first as shown below:

[image]

Why is this happening? Is there a concept that I am not clear?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to define multiple API endpoints in FastAPI with different paths but the same path parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74498191/how-to-define-multiple-api-endpoints-in-fastapi-with-different-paths-but-the-sam)

Comment: Related answer can also be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73113792/17865804). On a side note, if you would like to customise the order for the API methods in Swagger UI, please take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73210294/17865804).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ordering your endpoints matters! Endpoints are matched in order they are declared in your FastAPI object. Let say you have only two endpoints, in this order:

1. api/items/{user_id}
2. api/items/filter

In this order, when you request endpoint `api/items/user_a`, your request will be routed to (1) `api/items/{user_id}`. However, if you request `api/items/filter`, this also will be routed to (1) `api/items/{user_id}`! That is because `filter` is a match for `{user_id}`, and since this endpoint is evaluated before the second endpoint is evaluated for a match, the second endpoint is not evaluated at all.

That is also why you are asked for authorization; you think you are requesting endpoint 2, but your request is actually routed to endpoint 1, with path parameter `{user_id}` = `"filter"`.

So, ordering your endpoints is important, and it is just where in your application you are defining them. [See here in the docs](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/path-params/#order-matters).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Could you help me with something else? Currently I have the endpoints as in the second image:
api/items/filter --
api/items/{user_id} --
api/items/{name} --.
 As you can imagine now I have the problem with api/items/{user_id} and api/items/{name} since when I access api/items/{name} actually api/items/{user_id} is being evaluated.
Both endpoints have path parameters so there is no point in ordering them. What should I do in those cases? should i change the last endpoint to something like api/items/byname/{name}? Thank you!

Comment: You have two options: you could use different types if you can, like so: {user_id:int} and {name:str} and make sure the user_id is in front of the name endpoint (in order) because “123” can be evaluated to string but “onetwothree” not to an int. This only works if your user_id is an int though, if both are strings then you must indeed change one of the endpoints to be more unique.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have opted for the solution of using different types and it has worked for me!