# How to generate a standalone Swagger UI docs page for each endpoint in FastAPI, instead of generating API docs for all the endpoints in one page?

Tags: python, swagger, fastapi, swagger-ui

Is there a way to generate each endpoint on its own page instead of generating the documentation for all of the endpoints on a single page like below:

I would like to show, let's say, the GET endpoint for books on its own dedicated page without all the other endpoints. I want this because I am using an iframe tag to embed the UI for a specific endpoint.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve having separate Swagger UI (OpenAPI) autodocs generated by using [Sub applications](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/sub-applications/).

In the following example, you could access the Swagger UI autodocs for the *main* API at http://127.0.0.1:8000/docs, and the docs for the *sub* API at  http://127.0.0.1:8000/subapi/docs.

### Example

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/app")
def read_main():
    return {"message": "Hello World from main app"}


subapi = FastAPI()


@subapi.get("/sub")
def read_sub():
    return {"message": "Hello World from sub API"}


app.mount("/subapi", subapi)
```

If you instead would like to group/sort the endpoints in a single `/docs` page, please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73210294/17865804).